# how to cast a string value to its correct type

Tags: powershell

I have a function `foo` which I want to pass an Argumentlist in this format:

```
foo -ArgumentList "a=1", "b=hello", "c=15.00"
```

I need to know if the value after each `=` is an `int`, `string` or `double (float)`.

Here's my code:

```
Function foo {

    Param(
        [ValidateScript({ $_ -match ".*=.*" })]    
        [string[]]$ArgumentList
    )

    foreach ($Par in $ArgumentList) {

        $Split = $Par -split "="
        $ParamName = $Split[0]
        $ParamValue = $Split[1]

        if ($ParamValue -is [string]) {
            "2049" + $ParamName + $ParamValue
        } 
        elseif ($ParamValue -is [int]) {
            "2050" + $ParamName + $ParamValue
        } 
        elseif ($ParamValue -is [double]) {
            "2051" + $ParamName + $ParamValue
        } 
        else {
            Write-Host "Not a string, int or float."
        }
    } 
}
```

However, the Value is always a string, which makes sense since it's read from a string.

Can I somehow cast it to the correct type?

I know I could do something like this, however this is not reliable since e.g `1` can be everything

```
PS C:\Users\s> "1" -as [int]
1
PS C:\Users\s> "1" -as [double]
1
PS C:\Users\s> "1" -as [string]
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the value type's `TryParse(string,[ref]var)` method.

```
Function foo {

    Param(
        [ValidateScript({ $_ -match ".*=.*" })]    
        [string[]]$ArgumentList
    )

    foreach ($Par in $ArgumentList) {

        $temp = $null
        $Split = $Par -split "="
        $ParamName = $Split[0]
        $ParamValue = $Split[1]

        if ([int]::TryParse($ParamValue,[ref]$temp)) {
            $ParamValue = $temp
            "2049" + $ParamName + $ParamValue
            $ParamValue.GetType().FullName
        } 
        elseif ([double]::TryParse($ParamValue,[ref]$temp)) {
            $ParamValue = $temp
            "2050" + $ParamName + $ParamValue
            $ParamValue.GetType().FullName
        } 
        elseif ($ParamValue -is [string]) {
            "2051" + $ParamName + $ParamValue
            $ParamValue.GetType().FullName
        } 
        else {
            Write-Host "Not a string, int or float."
        }
    } 
}
```

I added `$ParamValue.GetType().FullName` so you could see the type being set. The `[type]::TryParse(string,[ref]$temp)` method will attempt to cast the string to the type. It will return `True` or `False` and store the corresponding value into `$temp`. `False` will yield a `0` value in `$temp` in our test cases. If `True`, `$temp` will contain the cast value.

**Note:** You must realize that as soon as you introduce string concatenation (`"2048" + somevalue`) that the output of that expression is a `string`.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks! I know that it will become a string in the end, it just has to be a string with the correct number in front :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can test limited types using `-as` like this -

```bsh
$val = '23.00' #input value to be type-casted

$intVal = $val -as [int]
$floatVal = $val -as [float]

if ($null -ne $floatVal -and $intVal -ne $floatVal) {
$val = $floatVal # value is float type
} elseif ($null -ne $intVal) {
$val = $intVal # value is int type
} else {
Write-output '$val is already string type' # value is not float or int, so use it as string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added some if statements with type casting to your function.

```
Function foo {

    Param(
        [ValidateScript({ $_ -match ".*=.*" })]    
        [string[]]$ArgumentList
    )

    foreach ($Par in $ArgumentList) {

        $Split = $Par -split "="
        $ParamName = $Split[0]
        $ParamValue = $Split[1]

        if($ParamName -eq "a"){
            $ParamValue = [int]$ParamValue
        }

        if($ParamName -eq "b"){
            $ParamValue = [string]$ParamValue
        }

        if($ParamName -eq "c"){
            $ParamValue = [double]$ParamValue
        }



        if ($ParamValue -is [string]) {
            "2049" + $ParamName + $ParamValue
        } 
        elseif ($ParamValue -is [int]) {
            "2050" + $ParamName + $ParamValue
        } 
        elseif ($ParamValue -is [double]) {
            "2051" + $ParamName + $ParamValue
        } 
        else {
            Write-Host "Not a string, int or float."
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks but the param names are just examples, I won't know their names in the future, so i can't use this

Answer (score 0):

As you acknowledged, you are setting the type as string when you pass the value to your parameter, it should always evaluate as a string.

If you set your parameter as an array your function might work.
example below, Get-Member shows the types of objects in the array.

How are you getting the value for your parameter? It might be better to change the format before you pass it to your function.

```
[string]$a= "string"
[int]$b = 1
[array]$array = $a,$b
$array | Get-Member
```